# Rolling Avg for Last 21 days

Tags: powerbi, moving-average, rolling-computation

How can I create a measure to calculate the avg spend for the last 21 days? My formula below returns a null

```
Average of Spend rolling average = 
    VAR __LAST_DATE = LASTDATE('Raw_Data'[Date_1].[Day])
    RETURN
        AVERAGEX(
            DATESBETWEEN(
                'Raw_Data'[Date_1].[Day],
                DATEADD(__LAST_DATE, -21, DAY),
                DATEADD(__LAST_DATE, 0, DAY)
            ),
            CALCULATE(AVERAGE('Raw_Data'[Spend]))
        )
```

I can't generate a value. It returns a 0

Answer (score 1):

Other than using [Date_1].[Day] and an off-by-one error with DATESBETWEEN that looks fine.  eg this

```
Average of Spend rolling average = 
    VAR __LAST_DATE = LASTDATE('Raw_Data'[Date_1])
    RETURN
        AVERAGEX(
            DATESBETWEEN(
                'Raw_Data'[Date_1],
                DATEADD(__LAST_DATE, -20, DAY),
                DATEADD(__LAST_DATE, 0, DAY)
            ),
            CALCULATE(AVERAGE('Raw_Data'[Spend]))
        )
```

Appears to work correctly for me with

```
let
    Source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("i45WMjIwMtI1MAQiJR0lU6VYHSQhI6CQoQGqmDFQzBhNzASkFU3MFKwXKBgLAA==", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [Date_1 = _t, Spend = _t]),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Date_1", type date}, {"Spend", Int64.Type}})
in
    #"Changed Type"
```